# Is it possible to import a group of import statements from another file in Java?

Tags: java, include

I don't believe this feature exists in Java, and probably for good reason, but occasionally I like to `import static` a lot of methods in multiple classes, or even `import static <package>.<Class>.*` a variety of classes (Mostly used in a static context, like C). Java obviously doesn't have any kind of `include` feature, whereby I could `include imports`, so I was wondering if there are any IDE plugins (Eclipse or IntelliJ), or other tools to support such a feature?

That is to say: Is it possible to import a group of import statements from another file in Java?

Side note: I am well aware that this type of coding is against Java style, and potentially misleading to other people reading my code, but this is for hobby projects mainly.

Comment: If a means is available to import groups of import statements from another file.

Comment: Can you make this clearer?  i.e. ask "Is it possible to import a group of import statements from another file in Java?  This is analogous to a convenience header in C..."

Comment: If you're using eclipse, is the Ctrl+Shift+O hotkey which handles all your imports for you not sufficient to alleviate any qualms with imports? With maven pulling all my dependencies for me I never really have to expand my imports at all, let alone write one myself - just type class name, whack those keys and voila.

Comment: You may code an IDE plugin to generate code "as you like" or use "standard" text tools (awk, m4, cpp). Anyway, it is not a good idea.

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl I most often use IntelliJ, which uses has import hotkeys, but it doesn't do static imports.

Comment: *sigh* I knew I was going to get down-voted for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right: this is the IDE responsibility. 
In Eclipse press Ctrl-Shift-O to optimize imports or ctrl+space while typing.

Eclipse has feature for satic imports too. Go to preferencies and type "favorites". Add classes you are frequently use to import static members. Now import optimization will work for static imports too.

Comment: That's actually really handy. I may well switch back to Eclipse for hobby projects...

Comment: +1 In IntelliJ if you type the name of a class, or even its initial like `LHM` it will give you the option to replace this with `LinkedHashMap` and import `java.util.LinkedHashMap`.  As such your IDE should be able to suggest imports for any library you have.  I would write the class name and let you IDE workout the imports.

Comment: @PeterLawrey `byte[] b = new byte[8] {...}; out.println(toHexString(bytesToLong(b)));` Is an example using 3 static imports. Are there any InteliJ features that allow automatic static imports?

Comment: Just tried Intellij CE (free) version 12.1 and it will suggested static imports for methods but not fields.

Answer (score 1):

If you are importing a bunch of the same stuff -- whether classes or static methods, you should also think about whether you are missing some facade APIs.

Even for hobby projects, you may be identifying the need to write some utility APIs, abstractions or base classes. Then, you import the single utility class rather than all the implementation details of said utility.

Let me give you an example. Say you find yourself reading some text file and extracting some content from each line using a regular expression. You can easily write an iterator-like API whose constructor takes the file name and a regular expression.